# Null the_geom values in CARTO / Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto

I have a CARTO map displayed via Leaflet (specifically via Leaflet within the CARTO.js library) using `carto.createlayer()`.

I simply want to get `the_geom` values from each marker as they're clicked on. Layer interactivity is set to `the_geom` but values are being returned as `null`. I can get the code below to return the values of other columns in my dataset (such as `cartodb_id`, `site_id`, etc.), but I don't seem to be able to access `the_geom` values using `data.the_geom`.

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: 'codemacabre',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: 'SELECT * FROM hydrous_sites_geo_map',
    cartocss: '#hydrous_sites_geo_map {marker-fill: #F0F0F0;}',
    interactivity: 'cartodb_id, the_geom'
  }]
})
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {
  layer.setInteraction(true);
  layer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
    console.log(data.cartodb_id);
    console.log(data.the_geom); // returns null
  });
});
```

See the screenshots for the console output (top) and actual dataset values (bottom):

[image: console output]

[image: dataset values]

I've read that `the_geom` can become corrupted when exporting / re-importing (such as in these issues: [1](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/6372) & [2](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/issues/192)), but I'm unsure if that's the case here or if `the_geom` protected somehow or (most likely) if I'm missing something obvious.

Is there a knack to returning `the_geom` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the coordinates from the Leaflet map as explained by @oriolbx, you can first extract the latitude and longitude coordinates from `the_geom` field using SQL:

```
  SELECT 
    *,
    st_x(the_geom) as lat,
    st_y(the_geom) as long
  FROM 
    table_name
```

And then after applying interactivity to your layer, you can show those new fields in a popup:

```
    cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(
      map, layer, ['lat','long'],
      {
         infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()
      });
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/393f3fb78962c84414179fbfedbaed48) is a working example.

Comment: Thank you, @ramiroaznar. To access the extracted `the_geom` values, I've used your first block of code with `data.lat` and `data.long`. I've read that CARTO.js [doesn't currently support using `viz.json`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations), so haven't used the `vis` function.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c) example might be useful.

Where  the part in which the coordinates are extracted  is the next one:

```
/* Enable mouse events with CartoDB layers */

        // 1- Set CartoDB layer interaction
        layer.setInteraction(true);

        // 2- Custom mouseover event on CartoDB layers
        layer.on('featureOver',function(e,latlng,pos,data){
          lat = (latlng[0]).toFixed(2) // show latitude of clicked point in the console
          lon = (latlng[1]).toFixed(2) // show longitude of clicked point in the console

        // 3- Add coordinates of the selected geometry in the div element 
        //  with id = "box" 
           document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = lat;
           document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = lon;
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help; the issue is specifically with `the_geom`, not the marker's position or `lat` / `lng`. I want to get the actual values of `the_geom` from the dataset table, but they're being erroneously returned as `null`.

Comment: This code returns the coordinates of the mouse, not the marker. So, on a large marker, you get many different points.